# Distance from ground to start suicide burn with initial height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, mathematics

In the figure below, the rocket is dropped with no initial velocity at a height of $h$. $d_f$ (free fall distance) is the distance in which the rocket is in free fall. $v_b$ is the velocity due to free fall when the burn is started. $d_b$ (burn distance) is the distance in which the thruster is then active with constant acceleration. Assume the acceleration vector is straight down. Assume the mass of the rocket is constant. The rocket should then provide just enough thrust so that its velocity is exactly zero exactly as it reaches the ground. This is also known as a [suicide burn](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10308/29963).

[image]

**I want to find an expression that calculates $d_b$**, or the last possible point at which the rocket must fire its thruster to be able to achieve zero velocity when it reaches the ground. I did some calculations but I am unsure if this is the correct approach.

This is not homework, I am just curious the relationship of height and distance required to burn for different gravitational force and thrusts.

**Below is my attempt, can anyone verify if this is correct, or tell me a better way to calculate this?**

I tried using these kinematic equations:

$$(v_b)^2 = (v_i)^2 + 2gd_f$$

$$h = d_b + d_f$$

$$(v_f)^2 = (v_b)^2 + 2a_bd_b$$

Setting the initial velocity:

$$(v_b)^2 = (0)^2 + 2gd_f$$

$$(v_b)^2 = 2gd_f$$

Substituting for $d_f$:

$$d_f = h - d_b$$

Setting the final velocity:

$$(0)^2 = (v_b)^2 + 2a_bd_b$$

$$(v_b)^2 = -2a_bd_b$$

Therefore:

$$2gd_f = -2a_bd_b$$

$$2g(h - d_b) = -2a_bd_b$$

$$2gh - 2gd_b = -2a_bd_b$$

$$2gh = -2a_bd_b + 2gd_b$$

$$2gh = (2g - 2a_b)d_b$$

$$\frac{gh}{g - a_b} = d_b$$

Where:

$v_i$ is the initial velocity, which is zero

$v_b$ is the velocity when the burn is started

$v_f$ is the final landed velocity which is zero

$d_b$ is the distance from the ground that the burn is started

$d_f$ is the distance of free fall from the initial position

$a_b$ is the net acceleration upwards when the thrusters are active, with acceleration due to gravity accounted for

$g$ is the acceleration due to gravity (is negative downwards)

Comment: You say you are trying to calculate $d_b$, but what values are given?  If you are given $h$ and $d_f$, then it is trivial without any physics at all.  If you aren't given them, then you're going to need to some other constraint, like a fixed burn time.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it pains me so much to see rocketry problems which say "ignore changes in mass."  It always feels like "How long can you stay underwater; ignore the fact that you need to breathe."

Comment: Nothing was given, I was just exploring the relationship with height and burn time. I was wanting to plot the relationship on a graphs with such an expression, swapping out gravity and thrust as constants.

Comment: I mean burn distance instead of burn time in the previous comment

Comment: As best as I can tell from the information you've given, there's no relationship between height and burn distance .  If you construct a scenario where it burns for 1m, then falls for 3m, there's a comparable scenario where it burns for 1m and falls for 4m -- it just has to fall for a longer period of time.  There's also a scenario where it burns for 2m then falls for 3m.

Comment: It's doesnt fall after a burn. It falls for some distance and then needs to burn once with constant thrust to reach exactly zero velocity at exactly when it reaches the ground.

Comment: Ahh.,.. That's what I was looking for -- I didn't see the constrant of having 0 velocity at the ground.  Usually that kind of thing is mentioned up front.   Also... isnt' that the absolute opposite of a "suicide burn?"  The entire purpose of such a burn is to avoid suicide?

Comment: It's named that because you wait till the last possible moment to decelerate, and if you calculations are off, well then you've killed your self. https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10308/29963

Comment: I reorganized the question so it is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost got it right. Looks like there may be one sign error (or a definition issue)

I'm a big fan of abusing symmetry to solve problems like these.  I hate actually running equations, since I'll miss something.  Since you start and end at zero velocity, it's rather nice.  I'm also a big fan of approaching problems in multiple different ways to get a result.  If you get the same result, you're in good shape.  You went down a very strong "write down the equations and turn the crank" approach with a great deal of rigor.  I'll go down the more intuitive approach, trying to find related equations which are much simpler, but require more connect-the-dots thinking.  If they both agree, that's a really good sign!

You spend some time speeding up, and then some time slowing down.  Since $\Delta V=at$, and $\Delta V_f = -\Delta V_b$ (to ensure the net change in velocity is zero), we see that $gt_f=a_bt_b$.  Thus $\frac{t_f}{t_b}=\frac{a_b}{g}$.

Now we can look at the distance traveled.  The distance traveled falling is pretty straight forward, but we'd need the velocity when we start the burn to use the simple equations to find the distance traveled while burning.  Fortunately, physics is symmetric.  The distance traveled while decelerating at $a_b$ to 0 velocity is the same distance traveled in the opposite direction: accelerating at $a_b$ from 0 velocity.  This happens to be independent of the falling phase, makign the equations easy.  Now we have two simple equations:

$$d_f = \frac{1}{2}gt_f^2$$
$$d_b = \frac{1}{2}a_b t_b^2$$

Dividing these, we get

$$\frac{d_f}{d_b}=\frac{gt_f^2}{a_b t_b^2}$$

Now we have a ratio for $\frac{t_f}{t_b}$, so we can use it

$$\frac{d_f}{d_b}=\frac{g}{a_b}(\frac{a_b}{g})^2 = \frac{a_b}{g}$$

Is't that nice and sweet.  The ratios of distances are equal to the reciprocal of the ratios of the accelerations.

all that's left is to add $h=d_f+d_b$ into the puzzle.  If we rewrite that as $d_f=h-d_b$, we can substitute

$$\frac{h-d_b}{d_b} = \frac{a_b}{g}$$
$$(h-d_b)g = a_b d_b$$
$$gh-gd_b = a_b d_b$$
$$gh = (a_b+g)d_b$$
$$d_b = \frac{gh}{a_b+g}$$

So we almost agree.  You have a minus sign, and I have a plus sign.  How did that happen?

Looking at your equations, I think I see the line where we differ, right near the top:
$$(v_b)^2=(v_i)^2 + 2gd_f$$
$$(v_f)^2=(v_b)^2 + 2a_bd_b$$

Note that the signs of the $2ad$ terms in these two are the same.  That means you are defining your accelerations in the same direction, so $g$ and $a_b$ have opposite signs.  However, you define these to be:

> $a_b$ is the net acceleration upwards when the thrusters are active,
>   with acceleration due to gravity accounted for
>
> $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity

Typically $g$ is defined to be a positive number (such as 9.8m/s on the Earth's surface).  The direction of the force of gravity is down.  You define $a_b$ to be a "net acceleration upwards," which is the opposite direction of gravity.  By that definition $a_b$ is positive as well.

So if you intended to use the definition you gave, my answer is correct.  However, if instead you intended to have all accelerations be in a consistent direction (which is a very reasonable thing to do when crunching numbers), then what I call $a_b$, you would call $-a_b$ because you would want a negative number.  If you carry this minus sign all the way through my logic, you will indeed get the result you got.  If you change your 2nd equation to 
$(v_f)^2=(v_b)^2 - 2a_bd_b$, you will get the result I got.

Comment: I assumed down is negative, so g = -9.8m/s^2. I plugged some numbers in to test, so let the rocket start at h = 1000m, and be able to provide 10m/s^2 thrust, which gives a net upwards acceleration of 0.2m/s^2 (10 - 9.8). Plugging those into your equation, I get 1020.8333m, which is higher than the initial height so I am a bit confused. I think your answer is right but I don't understand in your deduction where the a and g assign different coordinate systems, e.g your g assumes down is positive and your a assumes up is positive. My question was not explicit about coordinate systems either.

Comment: @dmoody256 Ahh, those numbers will help for clarification.  If I were to assign the variables as I did in my work, I would say $g=9.8 m/s$, $a_b=0.2 m/s$ and $h=1000 m$, yielding $d_b = \frac{9.8}{9.8+0.2}\cdot 1000 = 980 m$.  If you labeled the variables differently, you may have to tweak the approach I took.

Comment: @dmoody256 As for directions for a and g, your approach is consistent, especially in 1d.  I do a lot of work in 3d, where is it very convenient to think of vectors as made up of a positive magnitude and a unit-vector that specifies the direction.  Since I was going for a more intuitive approach, I naturally used the vector notation that I am most comfortable with -- for better or for worse.

Comment: OK, that clears it up, I like your answer because it intuitively uses the delta V in both free fall and burn to relate the distances to the accelerations. It makes more sense the relationship rather than the plug and chug deduction I came up with. Thanks!